# Handle 429 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension which will fetch out images from a site & upload it on my server, everything is working fine only problem is if there are too many requests it gives `429`, and probably it's making too many requests because my program has 3 steps to do this job:

1. Request-1: Images loading by site itself on scrolling down, same like google images.
2. Request-2: Click a button (provided by extension) this will go through the list and get those images and show the user all the images fetched in a dialog box.
3. Request-3: Create base64 to make file object and pass it to the server.

So is there any way to avoid making this many requests, like on the step one itself can't I store those images locally or something then use it in step-2 & 3 without initiating the request.

Comment: Currently this is an abstract question, so an abstract answer would be "why not?" It's not clear what prevents you from implementing local cache.

Comment: @wOxxOm so how I can cache an image locally? if I try localStorage then there I have to use base64 and when I need to show it to user then again it will be a request (image load) I will be making.

Comment: base64-encoded data:// url doesn't generate a request to server.